# Java Fx how to refer to added elements within a class

Tags: java, javafx

I added

`this.getChildren().add(new HBox(new TextField("Some_Text ")));`

in a class constructor, the class extends Java Fx Group. 
I wonder what to do to change the text in that TextField later.

For example, normally we can do this

```
TextField asdf = new TextField();
asdf.setText("Some_text");
```

but how can I change the text later in the previous example?

Comment: you can try to get the reference by iterating through the child elements. In the example you provided a solution could look like this: `((TextField) ((HBox) this.getChildren().get(0)).getChildren().get(0)).setText("someText");` But this is a realy risky and way of achieving this because of the casts. A better way would be to just save the reference like you did in your second example.

Comment: Store a reference to the `TextField` in an instance field of the class.

Answer (score 4):

**Using a reference**

As Slaw states in a comment:

> Store a reference to the TextField in an instance field of the class.

**If you use FXML**

If you use FXML, which is common for JavaFX apps, and place an `fx:id` attribute on a node, then use `@FXML` to inject the node into your controller, the reference will automatically be stored in the controller.  In some cases, this kind of shifts the problem from "how do I get a reference to a node?" to "how do I get a reference to a controller?".  If you need to answer the last question, then look at some of the suggestions in: [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml).

**Using a lookup**

If you really can't store a reference as an instance field in the class, for whatever reason, then [set a css ID](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setId(java.lang.String)) on the node and you can look it up later without having to write horrible code to traverse the scene graph to find it.

For example, replace:

```
this.getChildren().add(new HBox(new TextField("Some_Text ")));
```

with:

```
TextField textField = new TextField("Some_Text ");
textField.setId("myId");
this.getChildren().add(new HBox(textField));
```

Then sometime later, once the node is in the scenegraph, you can find the node by [looking it up in the scene](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#lookup(java.lang.String)) or a [parent node](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup(java.lang.String)) by:

```
TextField myField = (TextField) scene.lookup("#myId");
if (myField != null) {
    // do something with myField
}
```

Note the cast in the lookup. By its nature, a runtime lookup based on css ids loses the compile-time type checking you get from a stored reference.  For this, and other reasons, using stored references is generally the preferred way to reference things in JavaFX.